# What do these IPMI System Event Logs mean?

Tags: windows-event-log, bios, ipmi, ibm-xseries, ipmitool

I'm currently trying to troubleshoot what seem to be hardware issues with a x3650 m3 machine. Using IPMItools, I'm reading recurring assertion events from sensor type: 0F, sensor no: B5 that repeat the following:

Firmware Progress C2 00 FF

Firmware Progress C2 13 FF

Firmware Progress C2 00 FF

Firmware Progress C2 13 FF

etc.

I think "C2 00 FF" is the beginning of POST, but I can't be sure. Can anyone tell me exactly what these codes mean?

Comment: Or better yet, does anyone know of a complete list of event codes for IPMI?